# BadMethodCallException in Builder.php: Call to undefined method Laravel 5.0

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

As the title says I'm getting an error in Laravel 5.0 whilst trying to upgrade a Laravel 4.2 application.

The exact error message is: **Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::orders()**

I get the error when I try to fetch an authenticated users orders from a controller with the following line:

```
$this->user->orders()->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get()
```

A parent class sets `$this->user` as:

```
$this->user = Auth::user();
```

The user models relationship to orders is:

```
public function orders()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Order');
}
```

To confuse me even more `$this->user->orders()` returns the error I'm experiencing where as `User::whereId($this->user->id)->first()->orders()` returns the orders I was expecting.

When I dump both `$this->user->orders()` and `User::whereId($this->user->id)->first()->orders()` I get exactly the same output on screen.

Can anyone explain this and possibly point me towards the correct way to do this as my solution feels hacky and I'm sure there is a much cleaner way to accomplish what I'm trying to do.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies for answering my own question again, however I have found the proper soloution to my issue.

I had left the default User model in the App folder since installing Laravel 5, and this is the user model Laravel was using when I called `Auth::user()`.

I needed to change config/auth.php to use my customised User Model and all is working as expected.